# Browser session storage

Tags: web-browser, key-management

Is it some secure way to store private keys in session storage? or is there any place to store that info securely?

Comment: You mean the session key, right? The key used to encrypt the messages *for that session*?

Comment: Yes one of the keys will be that one but also I would like to create some trapdoor function to encrypt the payload data even I will use TLS 1.3 to encrypt the transport layer

Comment: You might need to explain your full context and what you are trying to do, then. Storing secrets in the session data is not what you need to do.

Comment: I know that is not the best approach to store these kind of sensitive data in the client side. The context will be that the private key, will get once I login from the server. After when I log out, it would be destroyed. I need to store in the browser using JS. I cannot give you more context because this is the task that I have to do (if it is possible) and I would like want some tips or help how can I start implementing that if it is possible.

Comment: I am quite noob in that space by the way hahah

Comment: Then just use the session key protection model. Burn that private key server-side too.